# Is there anyway to change the appearance of the EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want my `edittext` to be appeared as shown in `pic1`. My current `edittext` looks like `pic2`. Is there any way to change it through the `edittext`'s properties? and why it is changing?

pic1
[image]

pic2
[image]

Comment: "pic1" is the original Android theme. pic2 is the current "holo" Android theme. Please use the "holo" theme on Android 3.0+ devices, unless you really want users to think that your app has not been updated since 2011.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the look of an EditText by changing the background image.

As has been pointed out, the reason it looks different is because of the android version. I don't recommend you use the old assets directly, but you could certainly make your own to look exactly how you want.